# Developing an Alexa skill with custom wait time after re-prompt

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop an alexa skill with a custom delay time. Currently, whenever a user asks a question, Alexa responds to it and waits for 8 seconds. After this, there is re-prompt speech (if present) and Alexa again waits for 8 seconds. This 16 second wait is followed by session closure.

I want to keep the re-prompt text to be active even if the user does not ask anything after 16 seconds time out. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible because Alexa will wait for a maximum of eight seconds before closing the session. You can add a re-prompt to reminder a user that a response is required to continue with the skill interaction, but it is not allowed to leave the session open for an undefined period of time. This enables the user to ask for different skills and first party features without closing a skill manually every time.

As with natural conversation, if the Alexa service thinks a question asked is misunderstood or confusing, re-prompts allow Alexa to clarify and reformulate a question to get the answer Alexa is seeking. Shorten a re-prompt for brevity when a customer is familiar enough with the context of a conversation that they won’t need the entire prompt again immediately. The key is that you provide enough information to guide the customer, understanding that you are essentially 8 seconds away from losing that connection if they don’t know how to answer. While re-prompts must be understandable, they provide an opportunity to expand on the initial request to get the conversation moving.

You can find additional info here:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-design/available.html